# Django "evaluate" filter?

Tags: django, django-template-filters

I've got a view func like this:

```
def user_agreement(request):
    return response(request, template='misc/flatpage.html',
            vars={'fp':FlatPage.objects.get(key='user-agreement')})
```

And then the template looks like this:

```
<h2>{% block title %}{{ fp.title }}{% endblock %}</h2>

{{ fp.content|markdown }}
```

This works pretty well, but I also want to include some Django `{{filters}}` in the content. Is there an "evaluate" filter so I can do:

```
{{ fp.content|evaluate|markdown }}
```

And it will substitute all my variables for me? Or what's the easiest/best approach to this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but the following might work.

Treat `flatpage.content` as a template, and render it in the view with any context you wish.

```
# view
from django.template import Template, Context

def user_agreement(request):
    flatpage = FlatPage.objects.get(key='user-agreement')
    t = Template(flatpage.content)
    fp_content = t.render(Context({}))
    return response(request, template='misc/flatpage.html',
        vars={'title': flatpage.title, 'content': fp_content})
```

Then apply the markdown filter in the `misc/flatpage.html` template.

```
<h2>{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}</h2>

{{ content|markdown }}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I want to evaluate/parse it as a template. This is certainly one solution, but now I have to think about refactoring because I don't want to write that 10 times :)

Comment: If you only need to use filters in your flatpage content, then it should be straight forward to implement `evaluate` as a string filter.  If it needs context then it's a bit trickier. Hope you come up with a nice DRY solution to avoid writing it 10 times :)